# How can I remove the .html from the end of URL pages

Tags: html

I want to remove the .html extensions from the end of the file names. As seen on the website: tekmillion.com

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Need more info. Are you serving static pages or using some server side code/frameworks to serve your pages?

Answer (score 2):

Use this to remove extensions in your `.htaccess`.

> An .htaccess file is a simple ASCII file that you create with a text
>   editor like Notepad or TextMate. It provides a way to make
>   configuration changes on a per-directory basis.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*).html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/html/%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule .* %1.html [L]
```

Checkout [this](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/) reference to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way but it is not really good. You need to change the extension of your files from .html to .php and than you need to upload them to online hosting or you need XAMPP server.

Note: If you try to run files with .php extension the browser won't load them except if you have XAMPP server.

Answer (score 0):

change the name of the files to index.html and put them in separate folders

http://tekmillion.com/videos.html

**should become**

http://tekmillion.com/videos/index.html

and you can acees it using the link

http://tekmillion.com/videos/

and you will not see the .html